# Имитация нажатия кнопок в браузере

Tags: javascript, jquery, webbrowser

Добрый день!

Имеется подобный html код

```
<div class="b-main-form-field b-main-form-field--logon_button">
                    {{include "checkbox"
                        name = "RememberMe"
                        value = "запомнить меня"
                        tabindex = 11
                    }}
                    {{include "button"
                        style = "darkform"
                        name = "logon"
                        value = "Войти"
                        tabindex = 12
                    }}
</div>
```

Как имитировать нажатия кнопки Login на с#.

Пробовал решение приведенное ниже - не работает.

```
HtmlElementCollection ee = webbrowser.Document.all.GetElementByName("button"); 
If (ee.count > 0)
{
    HtmlElement btnLogon = ee[0];
    btnLogon.InvokeMember("click");
} 
else{
    ....
}
```

Comment: вам необходимо использовать javascript после загрузки DOM

Comment: А как вы пытались использовать это решение: `webbrowser.Document.all.GetElementByName("button")`?

Comment: и дополнительно - уже конечный html, без `{{...}}`

Comment: во что вообще раскрывается `{{include "button"
                        style = "darkform"
                        name = "logon"
                        value = "Войти"
                        tabindex = 12
                    }}`?

Comment: Это уже конечный html. Я его взял непосредственно с сайта, ничего не правил в нем.

Comment: в таком случае, какую кнопку вы хотите найти? Данная разметка - невалидный html

Comment: можете предоставить полный html?

Comment: этот пример взят с сайта myarbitr.ru

Answer (score 1):

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = 
    "$('input[name=logon]').trigger('click');" +
    "//без $:" +
    "document.getElementsByName('logon')[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))" +
    "//P.S.          аккуратнее с этим  [0] - элемент с таким name может быть не один";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
```

Comment: _Как имитировать нажатия кнопки Login на с#._

Comment: так лучше? C# не знаю, зато знает гугл

Comment: Да :-) мне кажется это уже более похоже на то, что нужно

Comment: Что-то не хочет этот скрипт работать

Comment: ваш html - не html. Код, который вы привели в качестве html, явно должен был быть обработан каким-то шаблонизатором.

Comment: @Darth, я не могу привести весь код целиком, так как он слишком велик. этот кусок я взял с сайта myarbitr.ru.